# React Native App not working with raspberry pi

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3

I am a newbie to react-native. I was previously working with native(java) android app development.
I am trying to develop a Bluetooth app with react native using the following library.

https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager

My App is discovering and connecting successfully with the SmartWatch but I want to connect it with the Raspberry pi. I think it is only discovering Bluetooth low powered devices. But basically I want serial communication between my react-native app and Raspberry pi. Can anyone guide me what should I do or use to have serial communication between pi and android phone via the react-native app?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey Rehan, even I am trying the same!!.
I am getting other devices but not getting Raspberry pi Bluetooth.
Did you get any solution??